# Observable<{}> not assignable to type Observable<SomeType[]>

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm learning Angular2 and Typescript. I'm working through the Heroes tutorial on angular.io, but applying it to a project I'm converting from ASP.Net. I've run into a problem which I think is due to my lack of understanding, though as far as I can see it matches what the relevant part of the tutorial is doing.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {RiskListSummary} from '../Models/RiskListSummary';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class RiskAssessmentListService {

    constructor(private http : Http) {}

    private serviceUrl = "http://myserviceurl/";

    getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
            .map(this.extractData())
            .catch(this.handleError());
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
       if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
             throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
           }
       let body = res.json();
       return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the line "return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)":

> Error:(20, 16) TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.  Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>   'RiskListSummary[]'.  Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.

If it makes a difference, I'm using webstorm (latest version), but I think this error is coming straight from the typescript compiler. I was thinking maybe I need a typings file for rxjs, but the tutorial doesn't use one, and none of the ones that I found with a "typings search" made a difference

The following are my dependencies from package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think that your problem is located here:

```
getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
     .map(this.extractData()) <== passing result of function
     .catch(this.handleError()); <== passing result of function
}
```

You could use just passing `function` reference:

```
getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

but this way you will lose `this`.

Or you could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to retain `this`:

```
getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
    .map(this.extractData.bind(this))
    .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
}
```

however you will [lose type checking](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html).

I would leverage [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions to be able to use [lexical this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this):

```
getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
    .map(res => this.extractData(res))
    .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
}
```

Without it, the `this` variable will point to the function where the call is made, instead of the instance that contains `getRisks()`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I'd assumed there was something like .Net's extension methods at work in the original example (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#). I think I'll need to start a new project following their example precisely to see if that still gives the same error

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, however no matter how I changed as above mentioned,It still not working. Until my college found this [map, catch defination as VSC prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJsrb.jpg)

so the proper change should be like (add type cast the following place)

```
getRisks(): Observable<RiskListSummary[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
    .map<RiskListSummary[]>(this.extractData)
    .catch<RiskListSummary[]>(this.handleError);
}
```

I am new to TypeScript. so this kind of [method signature] really give me a hammer on the head :(

But finally it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the `getRisks()` fn, you are types to return `Observable<RiskListSummary[]>`. However in your code, you are returning `body.data || {}`. I believe you need to interface your RiskListSummary[] to your body.data.

Comment: Yes, that also works (I changed the signature to private extractData(res: Response) : RiskListSummary[]). As a new javascript developer, coming from C#, it makes more sense to me than the lambda function as well. I'm not sure enough of the langage yet to say which is the best answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

I found the next: AccessTokens was missing. So,i made the change and it workted:
On your model (in my case Country) edit de file and change from:

```
export interface CountryInterface {
  "id"?: any;
  "name": string;
  "order"?: number;  
}

export class Country implements CountryInterface {
  "id": any;
  "name": string;
  "order": number;
   ....
}
```

To:

```
export interface CountryInterface {
  "id"?: any;
  "name": string;
  "order"?: number;
  accessTokens: any[];
}

export class Country implements CountryInterface {
  "id": any;
  "name": string;
  "order": number;
  accessTokens: any[];
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue while working on my side project, the problem here is the interface in the function that is managing the returning value **es**  `extractData()` you can give it an explicit interface which then correct the type of value you are managing.

example

```
private extractData(res: {status: number}) {
   if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
         throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
       }
   let body = res.json();
   return body.data || { };
}
```

and then the status type will be set to type on a compilation run time.

Thank you Lamin-jr