# Angular HttpClient return expecting observable<HttpEvent<any> rather than observable<any>

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm getting a compilation error on the return type when using HttpClient. In my function `GetPortfolio`, I'm expecting the `GET` call to return the json object of type `Observable<Portfolio>` but it's giving the error:

Type `Observable<HttpEvent<Portfolio>>` is not assignable to type `Observable<Portfolio>`. Type `HttpEvent<Portfolio>` is not assignable to type `Portfolio`. Type `HttpProgressEvent` is not assignable to type `Portfolio`. Property `name` is missing in type `HttpProgressEvent`.

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


export interface Portfolio {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class PortfolioService {

    private httpOptions;

    apiUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.apiUrl = environment.apiUrl + "/api/portfolios";

      this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
          {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          })   
      };
    }


    GetPortfolio(portfolioId: string): Observable<Portfolio> {
      return this.http.get<Portfolio>(this.apiUrl + '/${portfolioId}', this.httpOptions);
   }

}
```

From the angular hero tutorial and docs HttpClient requests should expect `Observable<any>`: [Angular HttpClient doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

So am I doing something wrong? Or should I be setting the return value to `Observable<HttpEvent<Portfolio>>` ?

Comment: your return type is correct

Comment: If you expect your `POST` request to return something, could you please post the code of your `POST` request, and not your `GET` ?

Comment: @trichetriche sorry that was a mistake.I meant to say GET

Comment: Okay, then your code seems correct. This issue is common to interceptors, do you have any ?

Comment: @trichetriche nope, haven't added any interceptors

Comment: Okay, last question, did you try with a class instead of an interface ?

Comment: @trichetriche yup, it's the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's strange, don't give error if you write

```
GetPortfolio(portfolioId: string): Observable<Portfolio> {
    return this.http.get<Portfolio>('....', {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            })   
    });
}
```

It's look like, the compiler expect an object with the properites headers,params,observe..., but as your object have no type, the compiler can accept it

even you can do

```
headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
GetPortfolio(portfolioId: string): Observable<Portfolio> {
        return this.http.get<Portfolio>('...', {
            headers: this.headers
        })
    }
```

Comment: What is `customHttp`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited. (I was doing tests with a service of my own in my own project)

Answer (score 49):

Typecast your httpOptions

```
private httpOptions: {
    headers: HttpHeaders
};
```

The typescript compiler is pulling the wrong `get` method type ([src](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L760))

```
/**
* Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns the full event stream.
*
* @return an `Observable` of all `HttpEvent`s for the request, with a body type of `T`.
*/
get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe: 'events',
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'json',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
```

When you specify the type with headers, it pulls the correct type. ([src](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L855))

```
/**
* Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns it.
*
* @return an `Observable` of the body as type `T`.
*/
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]},
    observe?: 'body',
    params?: HttpParams|{[param: string]: string | string[]},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'json',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
}): Observable<T>;
```

Comment: this was exactly my problem, the httpOption type for me was set up as 'any', as soon the type change to include headers typescript detect the correct 'get' method

Comment: This was the answer for me, but this is just ridiculous. It makes the entire http client overly engineered and difficult to debug if you're not careful with how you type things. Instead of adding the http options on the spot, I placed them as a global provided value at the top of the app, so I can just simply inject and add to any request I want, overriding as needed. It was at the constructor that I didn't specify the type as '{headers:HttpHeaders}'.

Comment: Where did you come up with this?

Comment: @DarinCardin I went through the source code type files of angular (:

Answer (score 15):

i solve this casting my header params like this

```
return this.http.get<SomeModel>(someUrl, <Object>this.options);
```

Comment: Great thanks.  You actually need to do `this.options as object` now.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by various answers, in short:

**your options have to be of type `object` instead of type `any`**

Answer (score 0):

As per [Angular Great Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

You can simply solve this by setting the observe in httpOptions to "response"

`getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> { return this.http.get<Config>( this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' }); }`

this will return `HttpResponse<Config>` instead of `Config` only if we didn't set `observe ='response'`

Answer (score -2):

As this is a service 'PortfolioService' we may not need interface here, instead we can use of type any, and also GET method is only necessary here.

```
GetPortfolio(portfolioId): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/${portfolioId}')
         .map((response:any) => {
              return response;
         });
}
```

This should work, please try.

Comment: using `any` will deactivate the auto completion.

Comment: I'm not the OP, and yes it will work. I'm stating as information that this will deactivate auto completion.

Comment: yup the code does work. But I'd lose the explicit return type, which I'd preferably like to keep.