# How to return the CustomType and not the HttpEvent<CustomType> from an HTTP GET call?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that sends a request and that receives some users as seen in the browser console:

```
HTTP event: 
{_embedded: {…}, _links: {…}, page: {…}}
_embedded: {userModelList: Array(4)}
_links: {self: {…}}
page: {size: 5, totalElements: 4, totalPages: 1, number: 0}
__proto__: Object
user.service.ts:49 HTTP response: 
{_embedded: {…}, _links: {…}, page: {…}}
_embedded: {userModelList: Array(4)}
_links: {self: {…}}
page: {size: 5, totalElements: 4, totalPages: 1, number: 0}
__proto__: Object
```

The logger are in the method:

```
public getSome(searchTerm: string, sortFieldName: string, sortDirection: string, currentPage: number, pageSize: number): Observable<HateoasPageable> {
  let httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('page', currentPage.toString())
  .set('size', pageSize.toString());
  if (searchTerm) {
    httpParams = httpParams.append('searchTerm', searchTerm);
  }
  if (sortFieldName && sortDirection) {
    httpParams = httpParams.append('sort', sortFieldName + ',' + sortDirection);
  }
  return this.httpService.get<HateoasPageable>(this.usersUrl, httpParams)
  .pipe(
    tap((httpEvent: HttpEvent<HateoasPageable>) => console.log('HTTP event:', httpEvent)),
    map((httpEvent: HttpEvent<HateoasPageable>) => {
      return httpEvent as HttpResponse<HateoasPageable>;
    }),
    tap((httpResponse: HttpResponse<HateoasPageable>) => console.log('HTTP response:', httpResponse)),
    map((httpResponse: HttpResponse<HateoasPageable>) => {
      return httpResponse.body as HateoasPageable;
    })
  );
}
```

It uses the get method:

```
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    public get<T>(url: string, httpParams?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        let options = this.buildOptions(headers);
        options = this.addOptionParams(options, httpParams);
        return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, options);
    }
```

But the `httpResponse.body` returns an undefined to the component:

```
getUsers(searchTerm: string, sortFieldName: string, sortDirection: string, currentPageNumber: number): Observable<UsersApi> {
  return this.userService.getSome(searchTerm, sortFieldName, sortDirection, currentPageNumber, this.elementsPerPage)
    .pipe(
      map((hateoasPageable: HateoasPageable) => {
        console.log(hateoasPageable);
        return new UsersApi(
          hateoasPageable._embedded.userModelList as User[],
          hateoasPageable.page.pageNumber,
          hateoasPageable.page.pageSize,
          hateoasPageable.page.totalElements,
          hateoasPageable.page.totalPages
        );
      })
    );
}
```

The custom class:

```
export class HateoasPageable {

  _embedded: any = {};
  _link: any = {};
  page: HateoasPage = new HateoasPage(0, 0, 0, 0);

  constructor(_embedded: any, _link: any, page: HateoasPage) {
    this._embedded = _embedded;
    this._link = _link;
    this.page = page;
  }
}
```

The subscription on the returned observable is done further up in the component:

```
merge(this.updateEvent, this.searchTermEvent, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;
      let pageIndex: number = 0;
      pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex;
      return this.getUsers(this.searchTerm, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, pageIndex);
    }),
    map((usersApi: UsersApi) => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = false;
      this.currentPageNumber = usersApi.currentPageNumber;
      this.elementsPerPage = usersApi.elementsPerPage;
      this.totalElements = usersApi.totalElements;
      this.totalPages = usersApi.totalPages;
      return usersApi.users;
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = true;
      return observableOf([]);
    })
  ).subscribe((users: User[]) => {
    this.dataSource.data = users;
  });
```

The console log shows that the `httpResponse` object looks like a `HateoasPageable` instance. So I was hoping to change the statement:

```
return httpResponse.body as HateoasPageable;
```

into the statement:

```
return httpResponse as HateoasPageable;
```

But then, the compiler complains with the error:

```
Conversion of type 'HttpResponse<HateoasPageable>' to type 'HateoasPageable' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
```

And if I simply have the statement:

```
return httpResponse;
```

then the compiler complains with the error:

```
Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<HateoasPageable>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HateoasPageable>'.
```

I'm now facing this issue since I activated the strict mode:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
```

I'm under Angular 8.1.3

Comment: console.log(httpResponse) so you will see your backend obj, sometimes you have a data property inside response

Comment: I had that logger in place and it showed the same output as the existing two `tap()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

To send GET request and get the object from response body you just need to subscribe to the `get` method of `HttpClient`:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
...
this.http.get(someUrl).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);  // here `response` is the object from the response body
});
```

If you have an interface for the response object, then you can use generic version of `get` method:

```
this.http.get<HateoasPageable>(someUrl).subscribe((data: HateoasPageable) => {
    console.log(data);  // here `data` is the object from the response body
});
```

You can find more about Angular `HttpClient` at [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: The subscription is already in place, further up in the component. I updated the question to show the source code. As can be seen in my question, I already pass an interface to the generic type of the `get()` method.

Comment: You are suggesting the `http.get()` method returns an observable of the interface type as in: `this.http.get<HateoasPageable>(someUrl).subscribe((data: HateoasPageable)` but the compiler in strict mode complains on `public get<T>(url: string, httpParams?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T>` as it wants to return an `HttpEvent` with `public get<T>(url: string, httpParams?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue after reading the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405006/958373) which explained that the typescript compiler was using a wrong `get` method. To have the compiler use the correct method, typing the HTTP options with a custom class was the solution.
So I added the class:

```
class HttpOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
}
```

and used it as a return type in the method:

```
private buildOptions(headers?: HttpHeaders): HttpOptions {
    const options = {
        headers: this.buildHeader(headers),
        responseType: 'json' as 'json'
    };
    return options;
}
```

Now, the get method could be implemented simply returning the custom interface and not returning the HttpEvent type, as in:

```
public get<T>(url: string, httpParams?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T> {
    let options = this.buildOptions(headers);
    options = this.addOptionParams(options, httpParams);
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, options);
}
```

Then the service method becomes simpler as well:

```
public getSome(searchTerm: string, sortFieldName: string, sortDirection: string, currentPage: number, pageSize: number): Observable<HateoasPageable> {
  let httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('page', currentPage.toString())
  .set('size', pageSize.toString());
  if (searchTerm) {
    httpParams = httpParams.append('searchTerm', searchTerm);
  }
  if (sortFieldName && sortDirection) {
    httpParams = httpParams.append('sort', sortFieldName + ',' + sortDirection);
  }
  return this.httpService.get<HateoasPageable>(this.usersUrl, httpParams);
}
```